# Node Archiver 'Headers Error' when unzipping large files (above 4GB)

Tags: node.js, zip, unzip, 7zip, node-archiver

I'm getting Headers Error when downloading files bigger than 4GB, with or without the **'forceZip64'** option.
The zip is generated on the go when streaming each file content one by one.

#### How zip file is created

```
// create zip archive
const zip = Archiver.create('zip', {
    store: true
    // forceZip64: contentLength > 4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
});
// pipe zip to response
zip.pipe(response);

// iterate targets download
for (const files of file) {
   const stream = await this.downloadFile(file.source); // returns Readable
   zip.append(stream, { name: file.source.filename });

   // await to download files one by one.
   await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // handle success
      stream.on('end', () => {
          resolve();
      });
      // handle error
      stream.on('error', (err) => {
          reject();
      });
   });
}

// finalize zip streaming
zip.finalize();
```

#### How zip file is unzipped

**Using 7ZIP** Ubuntu

- For example when I download a file bigger than 4GB and then I try to uncompress it using 7zip I will get following output:

```
7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700T CPU @ 2.90GHz (906E9),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 15587398396 bytes (15 GiB)

Extracting archive: files.zip

ERRORS:
Headers Error

--
Path = files.zip
Type = zip
ERRORS:
Headers Error
Physical Size = 15587398396
64-bit = +
```

**Using Unzip** Mac Os & Ubuntu (UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009)

- I will not get any error

**Archive Utility** Mac Os

- "Unable to expand 'files.zip' into 'Downloads'."
- "(Error 2 - No such file or directory)"

#### Results

**Unzip** program always work, **7ZIP** complains about headers but finally it's unzipping well and **Archive Utility** (Mac Os default) cannot unzip the file.

In all cases the MD5 checksum matches the original one.

Does anyone faced this kind of problems with files bigger than 4GB (2^32B)?

All that I've done with zip's below 4GB are successfull and without any kind of errors or warnings.

Comment: Used node module is https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver